# How to retrieve the data from Ubuntu one to windows 7?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have downloaded the zip file from ubuntu one for my windows 7 and when i open the exe file then it asks for id and password and after i enter them nothing gets displayed and the window gets closed. so how can i retrieve my data?

Answer (score 1):

The [UbuntuOne service was shut-down](https://one.ubuntu.com/shutdown/) as of 20140601, so there's a good chance that your issues are related to that.

You have until 20140731 to retrieve your data, which you should be able to do by [browsing to the limited file access page](https://one.ubuntu.com/files/) (after successful login) from any OS.

Answer (score -1):

Download [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) and try to open the zip with that.

If that doesn't work, explain in your question how the zip was created.

You talk about an exe file? Where did that come from? When I hear exe in combination to zip, I see viruses flying around!