# Ubuntu one storage - Is there any chance to recover at all?

Tags: ubuntu-one, data-recovery, online-storage

My hard drive broke. I had some backup on Ubuntu One, but now it is closed. The link "contact Ubuntu One shutdown support" does not work. How can I get in touch with people who were in charge of File Services to check if I can still recover anything? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the data from Ubuntu one to windows 7?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/490374/how-to-retrieve-the-data-from-ubuntu-one-to-windows-7)

Comment: No, unfortunately "browsing to the limited file access page" is inactive.

Comment: My apologies, that message was auto-generated when I flagged the question.  It was intended to help in managing the site.  As for your question itself; Ubuntu One has been shut-down, and any hopes of retrieving your data have been removed along with it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will not be able to get the data. As described in the shutdown notice, all files have been deleted at this point.